# SQL filtering without join in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a source table which is following

| SN | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold |
| 4 | Sam | NotOnHold |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold |
| 7 | Joseph | OnHold |
| 8 | Joseph | OnHold |
| 9 | Elis | NotOnHold |
| 10 | Elis | NotOnhold |

from here I want TSQL to return a table for all the names which were put OnHold at least once. My desired output is following

| SN | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | OnHold |
| 2 | Sam | OnHold |
| 3 | Sam | NotOnHold |
| 4 | Sam | NotOnHold |
| 5 | Alan | OnHold |
| 6 | Alan | NotOnHold |
| 7 | Joseph | OnHold |
| 8 | Joseph | OnHold |

I can reach my end goal by doing following

```
declare @t1 TABLE (SN int, name varchar(10), status varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t1
Select SN, name,status
from
(
VALUES 
(1, 'Sam', 'OnHold'), 
(2, 'Sam', 'OnHold'), 
(3, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold'), 
(4, 'Sam', 'NotOnHold'), 
(5, 'Alan', 'OnHold'), 
(6, 'Alan', 'NotOnHold'), 
(7, 'Joseph', 'OnHold'), 
(8, 'Joseph', 'OnHold'), 
(9, 'Elis', 'NotOnHold'), 
(10, 'Elis', 'NotOnhold')
) t (SN, name,status)
declare @t2 TABLE (name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t2
select DISTINCT(name) from @t1 where status='OnHold'

select a.SN, a.name,a.status from @t1 a INNER JOIN @t2 b ON a.name=b.name
```

This is a simplified version of my current issue but I want to avoid join for performance sake if there is a way to achieve this without it.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a CTE and a windowed `COUNT`, however, an `EXISTS` on a well indexed table could well be faster.

#### CTE

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SN,
           [name],
           [Status],
           COUNT(CASE [Status] WHEN 'OnHold' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) AS OnHolds
    FROM @t1)
SELECT SN,
       [name],
       [Status]
FROM CTE
WHERE OnHolds >= 1;
```

#### Exists

```sql
SELECT SN,
       [name],
       [Status]
FROM @t1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM @T1 e
             WHERE e.[name] = t1.[name]
               AND e.[status] = 'OnHold');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested with both CTE and EXISTS. For my table CTE gave me the highest optimized performance. CTE>EXISTS>INNERJOIN in my case. Massive thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
select *
from @t1 t1
where exists (select 1 from @t1 t2 where t2.status='OnHold' and t1.name=t2.name)
```